# Add variables to array declared before if else in swift

Tags: arrays, variables, swift, if-statement, task

Im trying hard to learn ios development and have followed a guide to build a simple  quiz app. I'm trying to connect the app to database by parsing from json. 
Everything  is working fine regarding that part. I now want to add the variables created from json into an array. 
I have declared the array before `let task`:

```
   var spormslaArray = []
```

I want to add questions to the array inside the task, something like this:

```
   var question[] = [id, questionItself, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, correctAnswerJson]

spormslaArray.append(question)
```

I'm getting these errors..

```
 App/ViewController.swift:127:41: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
App/ViewController.swift:129:29: Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
The task:
```

The task:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            var err: NSError?
            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
            if err != nil {
                // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else {
                let questions=jsonResult["data"] as? [[String:String]]
                if (questions != nil) {
                    for question in questions! {

                        questionNummer += 1
                        let answer1=question["answerOne"]!
                        let answer2=question["answerTwo"]!
                        let answer3=question["answerThree"]!
                        let answer4=question["answerFour"]!
                        let id=question["id"]!
                        let questionItself=question["questionTemplate"]!
                        let correctAnswerJson=question["correctAnswer"]!


                        println(id, questionItself, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, correctAnswerJson)

   var question[] = [id, questionItself, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, correctAnswerJson]


               spormslaArray.append(question)





                    }
                }

            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
```

Questions are hardcoded this way :

```
let questionSeven = questionTemplate("lol", answerOne: "av ormer (worms)", answerTwo: "virus infeksjon", answerThree: "installeres av en Trojaner eller en 'datasnik'", answerFour: "Bot aktivitet", correctAnswer: 3)
```

Then added to the array

```
   spormslaArray = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree, questionFour, questionFive, questionSix,questionSeven]
```

Then sent to a function to set up questions:

```
     func questionTemplate(question:String, answerOne:String, answerTwo:String, answerThree:String, answerFour:String, correctAnswer:Int) -> NSArray {

        //Set the question
        var quizQuestion = question

        //set the answers and the right answer

        var firstAnswer = answerOne
        var secondAnswer = answerTwo
        var thirdAnswer = answerThree
        var fourthAnswer = answerFour
        var rightAnswer = correctAnswer



        var gjennverendeSporsmal = 1



        //Add all the questions and answers to an array
        let questionAnswerArray = [question, firstAnswer, secondAnswer, thirdAnswer, fourthAnswer, rightAnswer]
        return questionAnswerArray
    }
```

I'm sure there is a easy noob-thing I'm missing. Do any of you see my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare it as

```
var spormslaArray = [AnyObject]()
```

The trailing brackets indicate that you want to instantiate it. Just using `[]` will make it of type NSArray which is non-mutating. Instead of `AnyObject` you should use the actual type you want to put in. In your case it's some array again. You can do that by declaring that type like

```
typealias MySpecialArray = [AnyObject] // or whatever is inside, maybe String
```

and then use that

```
var spormslaArray = [MySepcialArray]()
```

You get the idea once you use it.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm trying to do what you say, but It gives me an error. What am I doing wrong?  ' typealias questionArray = [Int, String, String, String, String, String, Int] ' -  it says I need to separate by "; "

Comment: You can not mix types this way. You need to declare it as `[Any]`. This is the only way to have a mixed type array.

Comment: I finally figured it out, and you helped me solv my problem. Thank you very much. :)